# How to set per message TTL with RabbitTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm using spring-boot with rabbitMQ and I'm wondering if I can use per message TTL using RabbitTemplate. So far I have :

```
@Autowired
   private RabbitTemplate rabbit;

   public void produce() {

      rabbit.convertAndSend("My.Queue", routingKey, message);
   }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create `MessagePostProcessor` and use it in you `rabbitTemplate`:

```
final String message = "message";
final MessagePostProcessor messagePostProcessor = new MyMessagePostProcessor(10000);
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my.queue", "routingKey", message, messagePostProcessor);
```

This will catch you message, apply changes and send further.

```
public class MyMessagePostProcessor implements MessagePostProcessor {

    private final Integer ttl;

    public MyMessagePostProcessor(final Integer ttl) {
        this.ttl = ttl;
    }

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(final Message message) throws AmqpException {
        message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("expiration", ttl.toString());
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method didn't work. It works if I change it to `message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration(ttl.toString());` From answer of @Zhecker

Answer (score 3):

If you're about to use `MessagePostProcessor` solution, you should add properties to your message instead of headers.

```
message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration(ttl.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitMqConfig.EXCHANGE,
                    RabbitMqConfig.RK,
                    String.valueOf(body),
                    message -> {
              message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration(String.valueOf(1000));
                        return message;
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to have a little workaround:

```
@Autowired
   private RabbitTemplate   rabbit;

   @Autowired
   private MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter;

   public void produce() {

      rabbit.setExchange("My.Exchange");
      rabbit.setRoutingKey("R.K");
      rabbit.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
      MessageProperties props = new MessageProperties();
      props.setExpiration(Long.toString(expiration));
      Message toSend = new Message(message.toString().getBytes(), props);
      rabbit.send(toSend);
   }
```